# How can these I convert these characters to a CSV?

Tags: r, csv, character

I tried to download a file from [LSData](https://www.lawschooldata.org/download), but it brings me to a page full of weird characters. The first few are:

> 7z¼¯'�DÙ™µUa�����b�������’³_èÚ†à]�&Jgl›Ü)ÉZKŒP7þò|¤ˆëÁëxŠ§u6²ã]’“Àé3lGê7ñ"!èÞ’ïjP³
> l½Öv<¹-žøZ¹`Æ âäùëOKä@;cÞ Žmï•&?^¢Ø"Á.=ù‚u|õ9žG<Þ`*‡è¶½ÈËŒøÂtŠÍÝê/ÂG×à×–R*§Ýj×zÛ¥™éwG—ï‘ývíõåò ÂÑ\‡W�Ü±ò§úßxlø¾Ö¾EºáPnÚR"økv§}6“SLÒ¢ø€m]-Ì«gÐáÅMŠWGU�µOÿDõ™}u¦HŠ_qŠ,/¦lÔ}Áô|,Òäêÿ2l«ª»°úö¡]+€™´í¿¢«|Ãw#êñ:t!

I have no clue what I'm looking at. How can I convert this entire page into a CSV, or in whatever file so I can use it in R?

Answer (score 0):

it is a 7z zipped file, you can download and unzip it to get the CSV file

Comment: Thanks for clearing up what it is I'm looking at. But how do I download it? It's just text, not a file that gets automatically downloaded

Comment: Right click on the link and select "Save as"